# how to extract the sub-string which is enclosed in between '$' and '/' (special characters) and then substitute the value of that sub-string?

Tags: r, string, extract, breadcrumbs

I have the main string as str and substring which is required named as su_str:

su_str = "$Region_Name" ,

```
str <- " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name/Billing/report.csv"
```

and the value of ***$Region_Name = ap-southeast-1*** that is in some other file.

I tried :

```
r <- unlist(stri_extract_all(p,"$ /"))
```

and it will give an error like:

> Error in stri_extract_all(p, "$ /") : 
>     you have to specify either `regex`, `fixed`, `coll`, or `charclass`

c_prop will be: 
Key:            Value
$DirectorName       :                         DF-1C
$DirectorPortName    :                     Ports, DF-1C
$MaskingViewName      : 000197801199, IS_LGLW9062_VIEW
$MaskingInitiatorPortName :   Initiator Ports, IS_LGLW9062_VIEW
$MaskingAssDeviceName :Associated Devices, IS_LGLW9062_VIEW
$PoolName            :      000197801199, SRP_1
$PoolBoundDevice      :           Bound Devices, SRP_1
$PortName             :                DF-1C:12
$Region_Name        :               ap-southeast-1
[image]

How to solve this issue, suggest some idea? Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your example, does it solve your problem? When using regex (or regular expressions), you have to escape special characters in R with two backslashes `\\`. It looks like using `stringi` the replacement must have special characters escaped as well, but I do not use `stringi` often so hopefully someone can chime in on a better way to do it using `stringi`

```
> library(stringi)
> 
> str <- " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name/Billing/report.csv"
> 
> # If you just want to extract the sequence of letters and underscores's after "$" and before the "/"
> unlist(stri_extract_all(str, regex = "\\$[[:alpha:]_]*\\b"))
[1] "$Region_Name"
> 
> # If you want to replace it with something else using base R
> 
> some_string <- "$Region_Name = ap-southeast-1"
> 
> gsub("\\$[[:alpha:]_]*\\b", some_string, str)
[1] " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name = ap-southeast-1/Billing/report.csv"
> 
> # Using stringi package
> 
> # Special characters have to be escaped
> some_string <- "\\$Region_Name \\= ap\\-southeast\\-1"
> 
> stri_replace_all(str, some_string, regex = "\\$[[:alpha:]_]*\\b")
[1] " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name = ap-southeast-1/"
```

EDIT: if you want a multiple replacements for the same substring:

```
# If the substring will always be "$Region_Name"

su_str <- "$Region_Name"
replacements <- c("$Region_Name = ap-southeast-1/", "$Region_Name = ap-southeast-2/")

stri_replace_all(str, replacements, fixed = su_str)
[1] " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name = ap-southeast-1//Billing/report.csv"
[2] " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name = ap-southeast-2//Billing/report.csv"
```

Comment: yes, This solution works for me efficiently. I want to ask more thing; suppose, the value of **$Region_Name** is not known as **ap-southeast-1**. Instead of that, its value is given in one of the entries like **$Region_Name = blah_blah** which stored in some other file other file named **c_prop**. the file read as `c_prop <- read.csv2("resources/configuration.properties", sep = "=", blank.lines.skip = TRUE, comment.char = "#",header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
`. then how the value of **$Region_Name** will be subsititued in **str**?

Comment: What does **c_prop** look like? Can you provide some more info on **c_prop** or post the results of `head(c_prop)` as an edit to your question?

Comment: I added the information about **c_prop** in the question itself.

Comment: Then, how the value of **$Region_Name ** will be replaced with **ap-southeast-1**?

Comment: Sorry Bhavneet, I am still not sure what **c_prop** is or how the data is structured in R. Is **$Region_Name** part of one column and the **blah_blah** in the same row of the next column?

Comment: yes, **$Region_Name** is one column and it's value **blah_blah** in the same row of next column.

Comment: I do not know the column names but you could always just filter the rows / columns that you would like with something like this: `c_prop[c_prop$col1 == "$Region_Name", "col2"]`

Comment: that's the good one to fetch the value.                                               
what if read the file as a hashmap. Then it may be easy to access the value of the second column from the hashmap and replace at where we want. Can I do this and How can we do this?

Comment: now I tried to extract the **report** sub-string from str, I tried `stri_extract_all(str, regex = "\\/[[:aplha:]]+\\.csv`  and  `stri_extract_all(str, regex = "\\/[[:aplha:]]*\\.csv` but it gave me an error > Error in stri_extract_all_regex(str, regex, ...) :   Start of codes indicating failure.(U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR).            where i am doing mistake?? plz tell me!!!

Comment: `alpha` is spelled wrong. Otherwise you got it. Well done.

Comment: okay, I made it correct `stri_extract_all(str, regex = "\\/[[:alpha:]]*\\.")` but its output `/Billing.` which is not required, desired output is `Billing` only.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question and the one you are asking are two different issues but I will try to address them both.

With respect to the Error you are getting with  stri_extract_all(), you need to specify what kind of pattern you want to match, I believe you are trying to match a fixed pattern, in which case you can use the

```
stri_extract_all_fixed()
```

function instead.

However I do not use stri_extract_all() to remove and substitute your sub-string. Here's my solution.

```
str <- " https://lglbw.pqr.xyz.com:58443/APG/lookup/All/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Regions/$Region_Name/Billing/report.csv"
reg<-"$Region_Name"
replce<-"ap-southeast-1"

# Custom function to return position of a sub string 
strpos_fixed<-function(x,y){
  a<-regexpr(y, x,fixed=T)
  b<-a[1]
  return(b)
}

part1<-substr(str,1,(strpos_fixed(str,reg)-1))
part2<-substr(str,(strpos_fixed(str,reg)+nchar(reg)),nchar(str))

part1 # Everything before "$Region_Name"
part2 # Everything after  "$Region_Name"

new<-paste(part1,replce,part2, sep ="")
new
```